# Trying to write my first Rails View Test in RSpec and failing with instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a (still) simple Rails application for books, and I want to test that the "show" page for an individual book contains that book's title.

The show.html.erb template is quite simple still, and as part of it, <%= @book.title %> is printed.
However, RSpec is struggling before that. Here's the full code of show.html.erb_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "books/show.html.erb", type: :view do
  context 'Show page' do
    let(:book) { create(:hobbit) }
  end
  it 'displays the book title on the show page' do
    assign(:book, book)
    render
    expect(rendered).to have_content(book.title)
  end
end
```

The factory for "hobbit" looks like this:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :hobbit, class: Book do
    title { 'The Hobbit' }
    year { 1937 }
    rating { 5 }
    condition { 4 }
  end
  ...
end
```

And the error I get is relating to the "assign" statement in the spec. I don't get what the problem is - the show page should know an instance variable @book?

```
books/show.html.erb
  displays the book title on the show page (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) books/show.html.erb displays the book title on the show page
     Failure/Error: assign(:book, book)
     
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `book' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::BooksShowHtmlErb "displays the book title on the show page" (./spec/views/books/show.html.erb_spec.rb:7)>
     # ./spec/views/books/show.html.erb_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I am sure this is a very stupid beginner error but I couldn't find anything that helps me with this?

Comment: you are getting error because you have defined `book` inside `context` block and `it` block is not nested under `context`, you should move `it` block inside `context` block.

Comment: omg I am so stupid. thank you very much. Now I get the error that the rendered output doesn't respond to a method "to have_content" - the error is "expected '<a whole lot of html...> to respond to 'has_content?'" ... but one step further :)

Comment: I think `have_content` is Capybara helper, you have to use this to verify -> `expect(rendered).to match /#{book.title}/`

Comment: yes - I used "to include(book.title)" and this now works. Thanks!

Comment: try to change `render` on `render :show`https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-1/docs/view-specs/view-spec

Comment: Please post your final solution as an answer and mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple problem was that I didn't install capybara!

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for Product show page test. Maybe you can adapt it for your code.

```rb
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "products/show", type: :view do
  it "displays all the widgets" do
    assign(:product, Product.create!(title: 'Hello Title', description: 'Hello World 1', price: 10.1))

    render

    aggregate_failures do
      expect(rendered).to have_selector('p', text: 'Hello Title', visible: true)
      expect(rendered).to have_link('Edit this product')
      expect(rendered).to have_button('Destroy this product')
      expect(rendered).to have_link('Back to products')
    end
  end
end
```